# How to choose struct based on condition

Tags: c++, oop, struct, polymorphism

I have two distinct 'struct' 'student' & 'employee'. I want to choose it according to string mentioned in the message.

```
struct student {
   string name;
   float score;
}

struct employee {
   int id;
   string dep;
}
```

I get message like; `$ST,16,JOHN,A` or `$EM,16,IT`

From the keyword like `ST` or `EM` i have to decide which structure to populate.

I managed to extract the type like `ST` or `EM` but when i write,

```
if (type == "ST")
    student x;
else if (type == "EM")
    employee x;
// long code goes on here to sort and populate `struct`
```

it says `x`is undefined. I know it is wrong but i can't solve this riddle.

How to choose `struct` based on the condition?

Comment: You need a common base class and use (smart) pointers or references (also `x` needs to be declared outside of the branches)

Comment: Those structs need a common base class, then use dispatching to call the right method.

Comment: They have nothing in common. Why (and, more importantly, how) do you want to use the same code to manipulate them?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, **show the code that causes the error you are asking about.**

Comment: @Quentin you are right. i got my mistake. I  asked wrong question. :(

Comment: The best approach depends entirely on what you want to do with `x`. The simplest is calling an overloaded function from within each branch, but we can't know whether that'll be ideal without knowing what you will do inside the function. As usual: context is for kings.

Comment: @UnholySheep Jumping to the conclusion that polymorphism is either required or even appropriate, is ... not for kings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP did tag the question with `polymorphism` so I assumed that's what they are looking for (however wrong my assumption turned out to be)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks as if your scope is wrong. So `x` may not be visible.

No clue how your code looks, but you could define a base class, a pointer before the conditional and assign memory via the conditional (I would not do that). Alternatively, you need to work within the right scope.

```
struct base {
    //whatever
};

struct student : public base  {
};
struct employee : public base {
};

base *ptr;
if (type == "ST")
    ptr = new student;
else if (type == "EM")
    ptr = new employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is equivalent to

```
if (type == "ST") {
    student x;
} else if (type == "EM") {
    employee x;
}

// other code accessing x
```

You can see there's a scope around `student x` and `employee x`. When the scope ends, object `x` goes out of scope too.

To populate the struct properly, you must process the struct inside the scope

```
if (type == "ST") {
    student x;
    // populate student
} else if (type == "EM") {
    employee x;
    // populate employee
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something common in your case. There is nothing except reading from string itself. You could create the object, then read from string in-place. OR this solution using (kind of) abstract factory pattern:

```
using namespace std;

// "Marker interface" common between the two structs.
// Virtual destructor to make this object polymorphic.
class ReadableFromString { public: virtual ~ReadableFromString() {} };

struct student: public ReadableFromString {
   string name;
   int score;
   char grade;
};

struct employee: public ReadableFromString {
  int id;
  string dept;
};

// Abstract factory function that creates a ReadableFromString
// from a string.
shared_ptr<ReadableFromString> readFromString(const string &source) {
    std::stringstream s(source);
    std::stringbuf buf(ios_base::out);
    string type;
    s.get(buf, ',');
    s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
    type = buf.str();
    if (type == "$ST") {
        shared_ptr<student> studentObj = make_shared<student>();
        s >> studentObj->score;
        s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
        buf = std::stringbuf(ios_base::out);
        s.get(buf, ',');
        studentObj->name = buf.str();
        s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
        studentObj->grade = s.get();
        s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
        return studentObj;
    }
    else if (type == "$EM") {
        shared_ptr<employee> employeeObj = make_shared<employee>();
        s >> employeeObj->id;
        s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
        buf = std::stringbuf(ios_base::out);
        s.get(buf, ',');
        employeeObj->dept = buf.str();
        s.get(); // This is to skip the comma
        return employeeObj;
    }
    return shared_ptr<ReadableFromString>(); // A null pointer
}

int main() {
    string sources[] = { "$ST,16,JOHN,A", "$EM,16,IT"};
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        shared_ptr<ReadableFromString> firstOne = readFromString(sources[i]);
        // Try to cast to student
        if (dynamic_pointer_cast<student>(firstOne)) {
            shared_ptr<student> studentObj = dynamic_pointer_cast<student>(firstOne);
            cout << "Student: " << "\n";
            cout << studentObj->name << "\n";
            cout << studentObj->score << "\n";
            cout << studentObj->grade << "\n";
        } else if (dynamic_pointer_cast<employee>(firstOne)) {
            // If not student, it could be an employee
            shared_ptr<employee> employeeObj = dynamic_pointer_cast<employee>(firstOne);
            cout << "Employee: " << "\n";
            cout << employeeObj->id << "\n";
            cout << employeeObj->dept << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Not student nor employee" << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```